# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project and it runs with jboss 4.0.2.
Here is the first stack trace:

```
     ERROR [[/JSF_Example8]] Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5005)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:274)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:91)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:357)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:68)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:46)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:272)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:897)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:394)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:964)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:775)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:325)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:501)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:204)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:277)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:272)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:897)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:273)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:964)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:775)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:722)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:434)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:315)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:195)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:463)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `jsf-ri.jar` is missing in your classpath. Download and add it.

Comment: I have implemented jsf-impl.jar, but I get the same error.

Comment: @Alexandra I think you also need the jsf-api.jar

Comment: I changed jsf-impl.jar with jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar and resolved my problem. Thanks